# How many ways are there to take 4 out of 7, 1-month courses in 6 months?

Tags: combinatorics

A school gives 7 courses during a period of 6 months. These courses are all 1 month courses. If you are going to read 4 of these courses, in how many ways are there to do this?
(Note that the order in which the courses are taken in is not nonessential and you can not read two courses at the same time).

Okay, since order here is a factor: the first time we should have 7 choices, the second 6, third time 5 and for the last course we should have 4 choices. 
Doesn't this mean that there are $\dfrac{7!}{3!}$ ways of doing this?
I don't understand where the 6 months come in, does it matter, we are only taking 4 out of the classes.

Comment: We are taking four classes in six months. That means that two of the months we're _not_ taking a class. Taking four classes in the first four months and then two months with no classes is different from taking one month off, then two classes, then one month off, then two classes.

Comment: @Arthur Oh i get it, thanks, I did not think about that at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot read two courses in the same month, so we have to choose four months out of 6 to read the courses in – the 6 months come in here. There are $\binom64$ ways to do this. Multiply that by the $\frac{7!}{3!}$ ways to choose and order the courses, which you have calculated, and there are 12600 ways to pick/read courses for the semester.